# Compilacion App IOS GX17 UP6

Tags: ios, xcode, genexus

Estoy compilando mi app a GX17 UP6

Actualice MI MAC a Monterrey V12.2.1 Y Xcode 13.2.1 pero al momento de compilar me entrega el siguiente error:

```
Calculating Mobile Targets for Frontend (Front end)
========== iOS Compilation started ==========
Command: MacTransfer BuildApp /env ".NetCoreQABrasil" /h "MyMac" /kb "GX_17_PostVentaCorpM" /m "D:\Respaldos Diarios\GX_17_PostVentaCorpM\.NetCoreQABrasil" /o "PVMobileOnlineD" /p <password> /rb True /u "Desarrolladorios" /v "17.0.154974 U6"
Connecting to MyMac
Copying Libraries to /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/17.0.154974_U6/
Synchronizing D:\Respaldos Diarios\GX_17_PostVentaCorpM\.NetCoreQABrasil\mobile\iOS\PVMobileOnlineD\ios\Genexus to /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD
Compiling
sshExec: cd ~/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme "PVMobileOnlineD" -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" -configuration Debug clean build SYMROOT=\$PWD/build 2>&1
error: CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/Classes/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals.swift (in target 'PVMobileOnlineD' from project 'PVMobileOnlineD')
error:     cd /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD
error:     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/Classes/GXAppDelegate.swift -primary-file /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/Classes/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals.swift -emit-module-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals\~partial.swiftmodule -emit-module-doc-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals\~partial.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals\~partial.swiftsourceinfo -emit-dependencies-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals.swiftdeps -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals.dia -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk -I /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/UserControls -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/UserControls/iphonesimulator -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/17.0.154974_U6 -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/17.0.154974_U6/iphonesimulator -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity\=checked -Onone -D DEBUG -D GXFRAMEWORKS -new-driver-path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-driver -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift -enable-anonymous-context-mangled-names -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG\=1 -Xcc -DGXFRAMEWORKS\=1 -import-objc-header /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/PVMobileOnlineD-Bridging-Header.h -pch-output-dir /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders -pch-disable-validation -module-name PVMobileOnlineD -target-sdk-version 15.2.0 -o /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals.o -index-store-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Index/DataStore -index-system-modules
error: <unknown>:0: error: module compiled with Swift 5.5 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.5.2 compiler: /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/17.0.154974_U6/iphonesimulator/GXFoundation.framework/Modules/GXFoundation.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
error: CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/Classes/GXAppDelegate.swift (in target 'PVMobileOnlineD' from project 'PVMobileOnlineD')
error:     cd /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD
error:     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/Classes/GXAppDelegate.swift /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/Classes/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals.swift -emit-module-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXAppDelegate\~partial.swiftmodule -emit-module-doc-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXAppDelegate\~partial.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXAppDelegate\~partial.swiftsourceinfo -emit-dependencies-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXAppDelegate.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXAppDelegate.swiftdeps -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXAppDelegate.dia -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk -I /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/UserControls -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/UserControls/iphonesimulator -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/17.0.154974_U6 -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/17.0.154974_U6/iphonesimulator -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity\=checked -Onone -D DEBUG -D GXFRAMEWORKS -new-driver-path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-driver -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift -enable-anonymous-context-mangled-names -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG\=1 -Xcc -DGXFRAMEWORKS\=1 -import-objc-header /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/PVMobileOnlineD-Bridging-Header.h -pch-output-dir /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders -pch-disable-validation -module-name PVMobileOnlineD -target-sdk-version 15.2.0 -o /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GXAppDelegate.o -index-store-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Index/DataStore -index-system-modules
error: <unknown>:0: error: module compiled with Swift 5.5 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.5.2 compiler: /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/17.0.154974_U6/iphonesimulator/GXFoundation.framework/Modules/GXFoundation.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
error: CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'PVMobileOnlineD' from project 'PVMobileOnlineD')
error: CompileSwiftSources normal i386 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'PVMobileOnlineD' from project 'PVMobileOnlineD')
error: CompileSwift normal i386 /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/Classes/GXAppDelegate.swift (in target 'PVMobileOnlineD' from project 'PVMobileOnlineD')
error:     cd /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD
error:     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/Classes/GXAppDelegate.swift /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/Classes/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals.swift -emit-module-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/i386/GXAppDelegate\~partial.swiftmodule -emit-module-doc-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/i386/GXAppDelegate\~partial.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/i386/GXAppDelegate\~partial.swiftsourceinfo -emit-dependencies-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/i386/GXAppDelegate.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/i386/GXAppDelegate.swiftdeps -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/i386/GXAppDelegate.dia -target i386-apple-ios9.0-simulator -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk -I /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/UserControls -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/UserControls/iphonesimulator -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/17.0.154974_U6 -F /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/17.0.154974_U6/iphonesimulator -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity\=checked -Onone -D DEBUG -D GXFRAMEWORKS -new-driver-path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-driver -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift -enable-anonymous-context-mangled-names -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources-normal/i386 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources/i386 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG\=1 -Xcc -DGXFRAMEWORKS\=1 -import-objc-header /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/PVMobileOnlineD-Bridging-Header.h -pch-output-dir /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders -pch-disable-validation -module-name PVMobileOnlineD -target-sdk-version 15.2.0 -o /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/i386/GXAppDelegate.o -index-store-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Index/DataStore -index-system-modules
error: <unknown>:0: error: module compiled with Swift 5.5 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.5.2 compiler: /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/17.0.154974_U6/iphonesimulator/GXFoundation.framework/Modules/GXFoundation.swiftmodule/i386-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
error: CompileSwift normal i386 /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/Classes/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals.swift (in target 'PVMobileOnlineD' from project 'PVMobileOnlineD')
error:     cd /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD
error:     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-/Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift -enable-anonymous-context-mangled-names -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/PVMobileOnlineD-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources-normal/i386 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources/i386 -Xcc -I/Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG\=1 -Xcc -DGXFRAMEWORKS\=1 -import-objc-header /Users/desarrolladorios/Documents/Projects/GX_17_PostVentaCorpM/dotNetCoreQABrasil/PVMobileOnlineD/PVMobileOnlineD-Bridging-Header.h -pch-output-dir /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders -pch-disable-validation -module-name PVMobileOnlineD -target-sdk-version 15.2.0 -o /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PVMobileOnlineD.build/Objects-normal/i386/GXEOiOSPermissionsOptionals.o -index-store-path /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PVMobileOnlineD-gjtftvaevlittlebontkyywmsmfj/Index/DataStore -index-system-modules
error: <unknown>:0: error: module compiled with Swift 5.5 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.5.2 compiler: /Users/desarrolladorios/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/17.0.154974_U6/iphonesimulator/GXFoundation.framework/Modules/GXFoundation.swiftmodule/i386-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
Failed: iOS Compilation
Failed: Rebuild PVMobileOnlineD
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema que estas teniendo es que la version que estas usando de Xcode no es compatible con la version de GeneXus. Precisas XCode 13.1 como maxima version para poder compilar apps generadas en GeneXus v17 Upgrade 6. Recien con el Upgrade 8 podes utilizar esa version de Xcode que tenes ahora.

Mas informacion podes encontrar en este [link al wiki](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?19478,Apple%20Requirements).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y puedo tener ambas versiones la 13.2.1 y la 13.1 al mismo tiempo en mi Mac ??

Comment: Si, entrando a developers.apple te podes bajar cualquier version. Luego deberias nombrarlas de la siguiente forma: "Xcode_XX.X" (siendo X el numero de version) ya que GX no soporta espacios en los nombres de las versiones de Xcode.